# read from exe files in vb6

Tags: vb6, exe

i want to read from exe files so i find this code

```
   Dim strData As String
Dim lngFind As Long
    Open txtAdrsOfFile For Binary As #1
        strData = Space$(FileLen(txtAdrsOfFile))
        Get #1, , strData
    Close #1
    lngFind = InStr(1, strData, txtFindString)
    If strData = txtFindString Then
    MsgBox "FIND"
    Else
    MsgBox "NOT FIND"
    End If
```

its need a command buttton and 2 text boxs

but its not working 
if there be a way to use that code if you guys can plz help me with doing this for multitipe strings i mean we can read more than 1 form a file
tnx

Comment: Can you please explain "not working"?

Comment: If by 'not working' you mean that the desired text isn't found (InStr returns 0), it could be due to case sensitivity.  Default is a case sensitive search (well, usually), thus InStr(1, "OriginalText", "text") will return 0 (not found).  The optional compare parameter can specify a case insensitive search: InStr(1, "OriginalText", "text", vbTextCompare).  As @jac says, a more complete description as to what "not working" means will be helpful.

Comment: i mean when i search for a string,this part of code well show up MsgBox "NOT FIND" i dont know why its not finding the string i am seraching for it! and i get not find! does the string i am seraching for it must be a hex?or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly instr() returns an integer of the position of the find string inside the search string 
It will not alter the two strings you pass it.

So instead of checking

```
If strData = txtFindString Then
```

You should check

```
If lngFind > 0 then 

    MsgBox "FIND"
Else
    MsgBox "NOT FIND"
End If
```

This is because StrData is still going to equal what the contents of your file was before you call instr()

Also as pointed out if you searching for text and aren't worried about matching case you should call instr() with the text flag

```
lngFind = InStr(1, strData, txtFindString,1)
```

Comment: Also bear in mind that this won't help find text that is in unicode format in the executable.